# razor/ ASP.NET Web Pages multiple buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have two buttons in the same page ( Razor/ ASP.NET Web Pages), how do I check which button I clicked,

so far I have:

```
if (IsPost)
{   
   //code block here 
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Update" class="submit" id="btnUpdate" />
<input type="submit" value="Clear" class="submit" id="btnClear" />
```

the problem  is (my low IQ, I know) it executes with any button clicked, only btnUpdate should execute the code block

Note: IS NOT MVC

note2: asp.net shows an example checking which textbox is empty to determine the action when a different button is clicked, is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but I use the "formaction" attribute that takes a full URL to define which method to call on the back end. Might be able to come up with something for your non-MVC needs based upon that.

Comment: thanks guys, I took ConvertToInt32 answer, it solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" class="submit" id="btnUpdate" name="update" />
<input type="submit" value="Clear" class="submit" id="btnClear" name="clear"/>
```

attach name attribute to buttons and check which one submitted via

```
    if(IsPost){
        if (Request.Form["clear"] != null)
        {
            //when clear clicked
        }
        else if (Request.Form["update"] != null)
        {
            //when update clicked
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    if(! string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Button2"]))
        Response.Write("{Button2  was clicked");
}
```

Comment: Error 2 The name 'IsPostBack' does not exist in the current context, I'm using razor/ ASP.NET Web Pages

Comment: this is valid in asp.net web forms not wep pages

Answer (score -1):

remove the "submit" class from your clear button, and change its type to "button"
.  This will prevent it from posting the form.